# What are hashes that begin with $1$...?

Tags: hash

I've found this hash and I'm wondering what is it.

`$1$h6k3X5db$pp8WQ5R5YYL5bNyQj2wP70`

Comment: This does not look like a hash, someone copied this from the shadow file, the $1$ suggests the rest of the string is an MD5 hash

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If that was produced by [crypt(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/crypt.3.html) then it is an MD5 hash.

> If salt is a character string starting with the characters
>         "$id$" followed by a string terminated by "$":
>
> ```
>         $id$salt$encrypted
>
>   then instead of using the DES machine, id identifies the
>   encryption method used and this then determines how the rest
>   of the password string is interpreted.  The following values
>   of id are supported:
>
>          ID  | Method
>          ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
>          1   | MD5
>          2a  | Blowfish (not in mainline glibc; added in some
>              | Linux distributions)
>          5   | SHA-256 (since glibc 2.7)
>          6   | SHA-512 (since glibc 2.7)
> ```

Comment: I didn't know that you could use salt with md5. Can you explain a bit how it works?

Comment: You'll have to check the [source code](https://fossies.org/dox/glibc-2.21/md5-crypt_8c.html)

Answer (score 0):

If it's a UNIX crypt(), then it's an MD5 hash.

As written in PHP's [crypt page](http://us.php.net/crypt) Normally, hashes starting with $1$ are MD5 hashes.  The $ signs are separators, but the the initial $1$ indicates it being MD5.  If you're looking to brute force this, most tools automatically detect the hashing algorithm.